# how to remove empty xml tags with clojure.data.xml?

Tags: xml, clojure

Given a namespaced xml (ignored in this ex)

```
<foo>
    <name>John</name>
    <address>1 hacker way</address>
    <phone></phone>
    <school>
        <name></name>
        <state></state>
        <type></type>
    </school>
    <college>
        <name>mit</name>
        <address></address>
        <state></state>
    </college>
</foo>
```

how would you write a function, `remove-empty-tags` with [clojure.data.xml](https://github.com/clojure/data.xml) to return the following?

```
<foo>
  <name>John</name>
  <address>1 hacker way</address>
  <college> 
    <name>mit</name>
  </college>
</foo>
```

My solution so far is incomplete and looks like some recursion might help:

```
(require '[clojure.data.xml :as xml])

(defn- child-element? [e]
  (let [content (:content e)]
    (and (= (count content)
            (count (filter #(instance? clojure.data.xml.node.Element %) content))))))


(defn remove-empty-tags
  [xml-data]
  (let [empty-tags? #(or (empty? %) (-> % .toString blank?))]
    (reduce (fn [col e]
               (if-not (empty-tags? (:content e))
                 (merge col e)
                  col)))
            xml-data))

(def body (slurp "sample.xml")) ;; the above xml
(def xml-data (-> (xml/parse (java.io.StringReader. body)) :content))

(remove-empty-tags xml-data)
```

This returns, after converting to xml:

```
<foo>
    <name>John</name>
    <address>1 hacker way</address>
    <school>
        <name/>
        <state/>
    </school>
    <college>
        <name>mit</name>
        <address/>
        <state/>
    </college>
</foo>
```

Clearly, this function needs to be recursive to remove empty child nodes using `child-element?`.

Suggestions?

Comment: Can you specify how you call the function? What is in `xml-data` etc...

Comment: Sure, I added the calling code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get to this with a combination of recursion and reduce (my original partial answer, complete). The key was to pass head of each node in recursion, so reduce can attach the transformation of child nodes to the head.

```
(defn- child-element? [e]
    (let [content (:content e)]
      (and (= (count content)
              (count (filter #(instance? clojure.data.xml.node.Element %) content))))))

(defn- empty-element? [e]
  (println "empty-element" e)
  (or (empty? e) (-> e .toString blank?)))

(defn element? [e]
  (and (instance? clojure.lang.LazySeq e)
       (instance? clojure.data.xml.node.Element (first e))))

(defn remove-empty-elements!
  "Remove empty elements (and child elements) in an xml"
  [head xml-data]
  (let [data (if (seq? xml-data) xml-data (:content xml-data))
        rs (reduce (fn [col e]
              (let [content (:content e)]
                (cond
                  (empty-element? content)
                  col

                  (and (not (element? content)) (not (every? empty-element? content)))
                  (merge col e)

                  (and (element? content) (every? true? (map #(empty-element? (:content %)) content)))
                  col

                  (and (child-element? content))
                  (let [_head (xml/element (:tag e) {})]
                    (merge col (remove-empty-element! _head content)))

                  :else col)))
            []
            data)]
    (assoc head :content rs)))


;; test
(remove-empty-element! xml-data (xml/element (:tag xml-data) {}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty simple solution using `clojure.walk/postwalk`:

```clj
(defn remove-empty-elements [xml-data]
  (clojure.walk/postwalk
   (fn [v]
     (cond
       (and (instance? clojure.data.xml.Element v)
            (every? empty? (:content v)))
       nil ;; nil-out elements with no content
       (instance? clojure.data.xml.Element v)
       (update v :content #(filter some? %)) ;; filter nils from contents
       :else v))
   xml-data))
```

This works by traversing the XML data depth-first, replacing elements with no `:content` to nil, and filtering those nils out of other elements' `:content` collections.

Note: the second `(instance? clojure.data.xml.Element v)` clause in the `cond` can be omitted if you're just emitting strings, because `xml/emit-str` ignores nils in `:content` collections i.e. it'll emit the same string either way.

```clj
(println (xml/emit-str (remove-empty-elements xml-data)))
```

Formatted output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
    <name>John</name>
    <address>1 hacker way</address>
    <college>
        <name>mit</name>
    </college>
</foo>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this code. However, when I run this code it outputs the same input xml with no changes. Can you please confirm if this works?

I have attempted to use postwalk, but it walks each keyword in the 'element' defrecord rather than whole element, and as such the logic was not straightforward to arrive at.

Comment: Note that `(empty? (filter some? x))` can be better written as `(every? nil? x)`

Comment: Can't use nil checks only as empty strings need to be stripped; this is ideal: `#(or (empty? %) (-> % .toString blank?)`

Comment: @pri I used the XML from your question verbatim. The walk functions will walk every element in the input, down to the individual primitives. That’s why the `cond` has clauses to look at specific values, and leave everything else untouched.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily manipulate tree-like data structures using [the Tupelo Forest library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/docs/forest.adoc).  Here is [a video from the 2017 Clojure Conj](https://youtu.be/RtavTnRr0oM) giving an introduction.  For your problem:

```
  (let [xml-data "<foo>
                  <name>John</name>
                  <address>1 hacker way</address>
                  <phone></phone>
                  <school>
                      <name></name>
                      <state></state>
                      <type></type>
                  </school>
                  <college>
                      <name>mit</name>
                      <address></address>
                      <state></state>
                  </college>
                </foo> "]
```

We add the xml data into the a new forest and remove any whitespace nodes:

```
  (with-forest (new-forest)
    (let [root-hid (add-tree-xml xml-data)]
      (remove-whitespace-leaves)
```

with result:

```
(hid->hiccup root-hid) => 

    [:foo
     [:name "John"]
     [:address "1 hacker way"]
     [:phone]
     [:school [:name] [:state] [:type]]
     [:college [:name "mit"] [:address] [:state]]]
```

We can walk the tree and remove empty nodes like so:

```
      (walk-tree root-hid {:leave (fn [hid]
                                    (when (empty-leaf-hid? hid)
                                      (remove-hid hid)))})
```

with result:

```
(hid->hiccup root-hid) =>

     [:foo 
       [:name "John"]
       [:address "1 hacker way"]
       [:college 
        [:name "mit"]]]
```

---

**Update**

The live code [can be seen here](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/test/clj/tst/tupelo/forest_examples.clj#L1521).

---

**Update #2**

If you want to run the code, you'll need something like the following in the `ns` form (see live code example above):

```
(ns tst.tupelo.forest-examples
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.forest tupelo.test)
  ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I looked at this library in the past but it has dependency nightmare with more than a dozen unrelated libs including reagent, reframe, schema, datomic, and the docs were not clear. That said, could you please edit the post with the code in a single function so I can test it out? It's hard to read code spliced with comments, when they break on copy/paste.

Comment: Got it. tupelo-forest could be an excellent standalone library with no deps.

Comment: I'm unable to resolve the symbol `walk-tree` inspite of `(:use tupelo.core tupelo.forest)`.

Comment: I'm unable to download 0.9.111.

Comment: Well, code blocks in comments don't work. But I was able to get a working function by removing the "dotest" parts of your answer. I'm still hesitant to add over 20 deps to write single function using tupelo, and it also forces newer clojure, cljs, and many other libs making it impossible to use it as a dependency. Do you have any plans to move most of your deps to dev-deps or "provided" scope? Even better, creating a lightweight 'forest' library? 

My interest on tupelo after this example definitely picked up and I'd be open to contributing. Thanks again for your hardwork.

Comment: Rather than that, I would suggest splitting the project into three 1) tupelo.core (no external deps) 2) tupelo.forest (dep on core and maybe xml/json) 3) the rest in kitchen sink until you find a way to further split them. forest is too good to be disappeared into a kitchensink. I can create a ticket and followup with potential contribution ideas, if you like.

Comment: Re. splitting out `forest`, I'll think about it.  It is more of a standalone tool than the other parts.

Comment: last note: the function doesn't work when used in production data as it explodes with a long stacktrace on enlive  

No matching method found: getBytes for class clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap

            Reflector.java:   53  clojure.lang.Reflector/invokeMatchingMethod
            Reflector.java:   28  clojure.lang.Reflector/invokeInstanceMethod
               string.cljc:  279  tupelo.string$eval23128$string__GT_stream__23133$fn__23134/invoke
               string.cljc:  276  tupelo.string$eval23128$string__GT_stream__23133/invoke
               forest.cljc:  538

Comment: Can you please add this as an issue on GitHub?  Be sure to include versions of Java & Clojure, please, plus some sample data that causes the exception.